# c++ multifile handling, redefinition of data members

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a hash table which incorporates linked lists. It spans across 4 files linkedList.h, linkedList.cpp, hashTable.h and hashTable.cpp as in the listing below.

linkedList.h:

```
struct intLink{
    int data;
    intLink* nextLink;
    intLink* prevLink;
};

class linkList{
    private:
        intLink* first;
        unsigned int numLinks;
    public:
        linkList();
        ~linkList();
        void append(int dd);
        void extend(linkList& ll);
        int pop();
        unsigned int getTotal();
};
```

hashTable.h:

```
#define HASH_TABLE_MAX_SIZE 1000
#include <cassert>
#if !defined(LINKEDLIST_H)
#include "linkedList.h"
#endif

class hashTable{
    protected:
        unsigned int TABLE_SIZE;
        linkList** tableAdd;
    public:
        hashTable(int SIZE);
        ~hashTable();
};
```

hashTable.cpp:

```
#include "hashTable.h"
#if !defined(LINKEDLIST_H)
#include "linkedList.h"
#endif

hashTable::hashTable(int SIZE){
    // c-tor
    assert(0 < SIZE and SIZE < HASH_TABLE_MAX_SIZE);
    TABLE_SIZE = SIZE;
    for (int i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++){
        tableAdd[i] = new linkList;
    }
}

hashTable::~hashTable(){
    // d-tor
}
```

I do have a problem with including "`linkedList.h`" into `hashTable.h` and hashTable.cpp without receiving an error from the compiler about the redefinition of data members. I please do need a way around this since both `hashTable.cpp` and `hashTable.h` need the `linkedList` class.

Comment: You *do* `#define LINKEDLIST_H` somewhere in `linkedList.h`? Also, it's customary to put the [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in the actual header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is odd for your `ifdef define endif`, it should be like this :

inkedList.h:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H 
#define LINKEDLIST_H

struct intLink{
    int data;
    intLink* nextLink;
    intLink* prevLink;
};  

class linkList{
    private:
        intLink* first;
        unsigned int numLinks;
    public:
        linkList(){};
        ~linkList(){};
        void append(int dd);                                                                                                                                                 
        void extend(linkList& ll);
        int pop();
        unsigned int getTotal();
};

#endif /*LINKEDLIST_H*/
```

hashTable.h:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H 
#define HASHTABLE_H

#include <cassert>
#include "linkedList.h"

#define HASH_TABLE_MAX_SIZE 1000

class hashTable{
    protected:
        unsigned int TABLE_SIZE;
        linkList** tableAdd;
    public:                                                                                                                                                                  
        hashTable(int SIZE);
        ~hashTable();
};

#endif /*HASHTABLE_H*/
```

hashTable.cpp:

```
#include "hashTable.h"
#include "linkedList.h"

hashTable::hashTable(int SIZE){                                                                                                                                              
    // c-tor
    assert(0 < SIZE and SIZE < HASH_TABLE_MAX_SIZE);
    TABLE_SIZE = SIZE;
    for (int i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++){
        tableAdd[i] = new linkList;
    }
}       

hashTable::~hashTable(){
    // d-tor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is because you have violated **[One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**. That is, you have included the declaration of same symbol more than once. To solve this, your `linkedList.h` file should follow the pattern:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

// file content

#endif
```

(or at least single `#define LINKEDLIST_H` statement in your case).

Additionally, using structures like:

```
#if !defined(LINKEDLIST_H)
#include "linkedList.h"
#endif
```

is *strange (to me)*, you should *rather* use guard macros in every header file, and not care about any other translation units that include them:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_SCOPE_UNIQUE_NAME
#define PROJECT_SCOPE_UNIQUE_NAME

// include whatever you want 

// header content

#endif
```

where `PROJECT_SCOPE_UNIQUE_NAME` is a unique name across your project, preferably the name/path of file written in uppercase.

Comment: Using preprocessor conditions around header file inclusions may seem weird to most, at least to those who didn't program on the old [AmigaOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS) where it was standard to have such conditions. (Yes I'm that old! :))

Comment: I have never programmed AmigaOS, I had C64 these days. But I edited my answer.